# Use IntelijJ as default diff/merge tool in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Has anyone maybe used Intelij as the default merge/diff tool in Eclipse?

I don't know what parameters should be used in the highlighted fields below.

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: I don't think IntelliJ support some command-line arguments to automatically show merge tool. Such ability to understand those arguments is necessary for the merge to be delegated. So I don't think what you're asking is doable.

Also, what is it you need from IntelliJ? The Eclipse merge tool is pretty complete.

Comment: IntelliJ binary can be used as a external diff/merge tool. I just don't want use the Eclipse default.

Comment: Ok, my bad. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html , it seems like you have to add a `diff` parameter, use no comma nor `and`

Comment: Works. Post an answer so I can accept it. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html about what kind of command-line parameters IntelliJ expects for the diff/merge: it seems like you have to add a `diff` argument first and then use the `${file1Path}` and other placeholders separated with spaces, without using any comma nor `and`.